# Как отобразить дату активности пользователя в группе. Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Народ, уже долго мучаюсь с выводом даты активности пользователя в группе. Пользователей отобразил, отфильтровал по группам а как вывести их дату активности не понимаю.

```html
<?
global $USER;
$arfilter = Array(
            "ID" => $_REQUEST['MANAGER_ID'].' | '.$_REQUEST['USES_ID'],
   "UF_TO_KVALIF"=> "1"
        );
        $arParameters = array(
            'SELECT' => array("UF_*")
        );
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="asc"), $arfilter, $arParameters);
$is_filtered = $rsUsers->is_filtered; // отфильтрована ли выборка ?
$rsUsers->NavStart(50); // разбиваем постранично по 50 записей
echo $rsUsers->NavPrint(GetMessage("PAGES")); // печатаем постраничную навигацию
while($rsUsers->NavNext(true, "f_")) :
    echo "[".$f_ID."] (".$f_LOGIN.") ".$f_NAME." ".$f_LAST_NAME."<br>"; 
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод `GetUserGroupList` который возвращает GROUP_ID - ID группы DATE_ACTIVE_FROM - дату начала активности и DATE_ACTIVE_TO - дату окончания активности.

```
$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList(1);
while ($arGroup = $res->Fetch()){
    print "<pre>"; print_r($arGroup); print "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо уже нашел этот метод и использовал его!